# Difference between B b and A<B> b

Tags: java, types

Assume class B extends class A and I want to declare a variable for B. What is more efficient and why?

1. `B b`
   OR
2. `A<B> b`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing two different concepts.

```
class B extends A {

}
```

means that `B` *is an* `A`.

If you have something like `A<B>` it means that you class `A` is defined as

```
class A<T> {

}
```

meaning that you class `A` is a generic class.

For example (over simplified) you have

```
class List<T> {

}
```

So if `T` takes the value `String` you would have `List<String>` meaning a list of Strings

So `A<B>` does not mean that `B extends A`.

You should use `B b`.

Comment: your explanation made clear what others were referring to. Thanks!!
Anyways..Thanks a lot all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `B b`.  `A<B>` is a template class that uses `B` as a type, for example:

- `List<String>` is a list of strings, so `List<B>` would be a list of `B` objects.
- `WeakReference<String>` is a a weak reference to a string, so `WeakReference<B>` would be a weak reference to a `B` object.

Answer (score 1):

If B extends A then I would use type A as much as possible.

A widget = new B();

This lowers the assumptions other parts of the code may make on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Neither declaration is more efficient than the other.

But `A<B> b` doesn't declare a reference of type `B`, it declares a reference of type `A` that is templated on type `B`.

Unless A is a generic class, the second form is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a matter of efficiency but of usage. If a pure A object isn't meant to use B, why would you want it to be `A<B> b`?

Answer (score 0):

Your declarations don't do remotely the same thing. The first declares an object of type `B`, while the second declares an object of type `A<T>`, where *T* is a type parameter whose slot is filled by the type `B`.